# Difference between "Connected" and "Connected to Microsoft Exchange" in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Not sure if this is the correct forum to post this in, but I'm curious if anyone can point me toward some documentation that explains the difference. I am running Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit Professional, and Exchange 2010.

Occasionally, Outlook will display as "Connected" in the lower right corner with a blue globe icon.

[image: Blue Globe Icon]

Other times, Outlook will display as "Connected to Microsoft Exchange" with the orange Exchange icon instead.

[image: Orange Exchange Icon]

I can confirm that I'm always connected to the exchange server via Outlook Anywhere, as looking at the Connection Status shows my connection type as HTTPS.

My main question is, **what is the difference between these two**? I was originally thinking it was something with cached vs. non-cached mode, but that would say "Online" vs. "Connected."

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by running the following macro in Outlook while being in one of the connection modes (different icons):

```
Sub ConnectionMode()
    MsgBox CStr(Session.ExchangeConnectionMode)
End Sub
```

This macro will show you the value of current Exchange connection mode:

```
olNoExchange = 0,
olOffline = 100,
olCachedOffline = 200,
olDisconnected = 300,
olCachedDisconnected = 400,
olCachedConnectedHeaders = 500,
olCachedConnectedDrizzle = 600,
olCachedConnectedFull = 700,
olOnline = 800
```

Here is the description of each mode available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olexchangeconnectionmode.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seemed promising, but I'm only getting return values of 700 (olCachedConnectedFull) for both icons.

One thing to note, the Connected icon with the blue globe is only showing up for shared calendars where the user has elevated delegate permissions. When I click on that shared calendar, and the icon changes, the macro returns 700. It was worth a shot, thanks!